# How to calculate Merkle Root? Need to reverse?

Tags: hash, coinbase-transaction, merkle-tree

I downloaded the necessary information and made the coinbase. Then I calculated the merkle root... But I always get an error message when I submit a block: "bad-txnmerkleroot". Tere is my code:

```
def dblsha(d)->bytes:

    return hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(d).digest()).digest()


def makeMerkleRoot()->None:

    global merkleroot,txnlist
    txnlist=[coinbase]+[unhexlify(a['data']) for a in tmpl['transactions']]
    merklehashes=[dblsha(t)[::-1] for t in txnlist]
    while len(merklehashes)>1:
        if len(merklehashes)%2:
            merklehashes.append(merklehashes[-1])
        merklehashes=[dblsha(merklehashes[i]+merklehashes[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(merklehashes),2)]
    merkleroot=merklehashes[0][::-1]
```

1. I reversed the data of all transactions(include coinbase)
2. I calculated the hashes(bytes)
3. I calculated the merkleroot(bytes)
4. I reversed the merkleroot
5. I converted the merkleroot(bytes) to hex
   But always get an error: 'bad-txnmerkleroot', regardless of whether I inverted it or not, or how many times. Do I really need to reverse the data during the calculation? By the way, I tested the code in regtest. Should I test the code on the main network? Are there other reasons for the 'bad-txnmerkle' error? Like the wrong coinbase. I'm really at my wits' end.

Answer (score 0):

> You should not need to reverse anything; hashes are never reversed in Bitcoin, except for human display purposes. So if you start from txids you get from an explorer or RPC output, then you should reverse those (to unreverse them), but other than that, none are used.

---

<sub>[About stealing comments and posting them as answers](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/839/13866)</sub>

Comment: I tried to cancel all inversions, but still got the error "ProcessNewBlock: AcceptBlock FAILED (bad-txnmrklroot, hashMerkleRoot mismatch)". I'm getting crazy with this question.

Comment: Can update your question to reflect your updated code, specifically how are you submitting the result to `bitcoind`?